# syslog-ng balabit client keeps opened deleted journal log files

Tags: lsof, syslog-ng, systemd-journald

OS: `CentOs 7`
syslog-ng -V:
`syslog-ng-premium-edition 5 F6 (5.6.1b)`
`Installer-Version: 5.6.1b`

Real problem:
syslog-ng keeps in open state deleted journal log files:

`syslog-ng 15305 30257           root  DEL       REG               0,18             10007708 /run/log/journal/c338cb13ed2048528bc1f413d4325e58/system@ae40947169c243bfb6cf079cd1afc6da-000000000049d90e-00054398e2bac964.journal`

Real issue is that /run partition runs out of free space.

Comment: Did you try to send SIGHUP to syslog-ng to perform a close on open files?

Comment: Yes. No effect.

Comment: Hi, you can set journald to keep a certain amount of disk free to running out of space (for an example, see here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=172399). Otherwise, the open fd might be a bug in syslog-ng PE, you can open a support ticket about it at https://support.balabit.com (or if you can reproduce it with the syslog-ng Open Source version, on github: https://github.com/balabit/syslog-ng/issues )

Comment: We had two `syslog-ng` processes! One started with init.d and other one with systemctl. After we stopped one with init.d, issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You clould also tryy NXLog instead, it's an open source [log management](https://nxlog.co/products/nxlog-community-edition) tool you can download for free.

Comment: This would be  a better answer if it said where we can get this NXLog software.  Oh, and, are you affiliated with it (e.g., did you write it)? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.